# Customization Spartacus Category Page breaking Bootstrap Framework cols and rows ideology

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to customize storefront (especially, Category Page) and faced with following issue:
Plain html structure which is based on Bootstrap Framework looks like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3">facets here</div>
   <div class="col-lg-9">list of products here</div>
</div>
```

I created custom ProductListComponent & ProductListItemComponent components (in Spartacus side). Currently structure in Browser Inspector looks like:

```
<cx-page-layout class="ProductListPageTemplate">
  <div class="row">
    <cx-page-slot class="ProductLeftRefinements">
      <product-facet-navigation>
          <div class="col-lg-3">facets here</div>
      </product-facet-navigation>
    </cx-page-slot>
    <cx-page-slot class="ProductListSlot">
      <product-list>
          <div class="col-lg-9">list of products here</div>
      </product-list>
    </cx-page-slot>
  </div>
</cx-page-layout>
```

The main issue is that having wrapper tags like `<cx-page-slot>`, it breaks displaying blocks
How can I solve it in Spartacus?
I try to say that, e.g. in our case `div's` with `col-lg-*` should be placed near each other to prevent breaking Bootstrap Framework logic

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a `display: contents` rule that you can use to ensure that certain elements are ignored by the CSS layer, so that you wouldn't break the CSS flow.

You could apply:

```css
cx-page-slot {
  display: contents;
}
```

I've not tested this with Spartacus, but I believe this works. Can you double check and feedback to us?

Comment: It make sense. But there is best way, I think. The way is to do not use ngFor directive to loop throw all slots. I used cx-page-slot in places where it is needed with particular position name. Each one is wrapped by tags I need (e.g. div.col-md-12). The same way is used in storefront based on JSP.